# Appcelerator. Get data from request out of onload function

Tags: appcelerator

I am working with Appcelerator Titanium and I am making requests to a remote API.
I need to get the results of a request out of the onload function and into another calling function. The request call is located in a function of its own in another file that is included in the main .js file.

This is my code: http://pastie.org/1731674

How can it be altered to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `loadPhones()` to accept a callback that accepts the output as a parameter

```
function loadPhones( callback ) {

    (...)

    xhr.onload = function() {

        (...)

        if ( 'function' == typeof callback ) {
            callback(output);
        }
    }

    (...)
}
```

And then, in **app.js** or wherever you call `loadPhones()` from

```
loadPhones( function( data ) {

    // do whatever with data

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I cannot get it to work. This is the settings I have done now, but does not return anything, I only get errors: http://pastie.org/1732491 and in the "calling file": http://pastie.org/1732492. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the nature of the errors?  Can you do a pastie of the console?

Comment: I am using this now: http://pastie.org/1732572 and it works perfectly. Thanks!! But now I can only add one section, how can I modify the above snippet to just add to an array and then insert the array into the table?

Comment: Is `table` a `Ti.UI.tableView`?  There are methods on that object for adding rows or sections at a time.  Check the docs (http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/API_TitaniumModule.pdf) or make a new SO question

Comment: Yes, table is a table view. Will check the docs. Thanks for all help!